# Insert values of dataframe to class atributes with for loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have parsed data in dataframes by using Pandas. I need to insert the data into class that I created.

My class:

```
class Message:
time = None
id = None
type = None
source = None
destination = None
    def __init__(self, time, id, type, source, destination):
    self.time = time
    self.id = id
    self.type = type
    self.source = source
    self.destination = destination
```

I'm going through the dataframes and trying to insert the output into the attributes of the class as following:

```
newMessage=Message()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    newMessage.__init__(row['time'], row['id'], row['type'], row['source'], row['destination'])
    print(row['time'], row['ID'], row['TYPE'], row['Source'], row['Destination'])
```

The exception it throws:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 7 required positional arguments
```

I don't know how to call the class and the arguments, please help.

Comment: Before the for-loop, `newMessage=Message()` is trying to create a `Message` object, but you're not passing in any of the required arguments such as `time`, `id`, etc. It can't know what you want those values to be, so it gives an error. I'd suggest working through a python classes tutorial like https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like that:

```
class Message:

    time = None
    id_ = None
    type_ = None
    source = None
    destination = None


def __init__(self, time, id_, type_, source, destination):
    self.time = time
    self.id_ = id_
    self.type_ = type_
    self.source = source
    self.destination = destination

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    newTelegram = Message(row['time'], row['id'], row['type'], row['source'], row['destination'])
 
 print(newTelegram.time)
 print(getattr(newTelegram, "time"))
```

Note that both id & type are keywords in Python.

Comment: I think that is what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can explore the powerful use of dataclasses or NamedTuple:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Message:
    time: str    #adjust the datatype to suit your usecase
    id:  int
    type_: str
    source:  str
    destination: str 

for index, value in df.iterrows():
    newTelegram = Message(*value)# unpack the values
```

Comment: That one looks good too. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: did you mean *value

Comment: oh yeah, my bad. thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about the below ? Use [dataclass](https://realpython.com/python-data-classes/) and get a clean solution

```
import pandas as pd
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Point:
  x: int
  y: int

points = []
df = pd.DataFrame([{'x':12,'y':6},{'x':45,'y':33}])
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  points.append(Point(**row))
print(points)
```

output

```
[Point(x=12, y=6), Point(x=45, y=33)]
```